# API Server: Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: invalid bearer token

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-apiserver, kubespray

I set up a sample Kubernetes Cluster with 3 master nodes and 2 worker nodes.
I tried to connect it to an OpenId Provider (in my case Keycloak). But when querying the API I get the following message from kubectl:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

or via curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -k https://192.168.178.30:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

and in the API server logs it says

```
Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: invalid bearer token
```

According to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) my token seems to be valid.

### Configuration of the API server

In the API server I specified the following parameters:

```
oidc-issuer-url: https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master
oidc-client-id: account
oidc-ca-file: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/keycloak-rootCA.pem
oidc-username-claim: sub
oidc-groups-claim: groups
```

*I had to specify the CA file, because the certificate used for keycloak was a self signed one*

The certificate seems to work, because a curl without the CA file results in an error; where specifying the CA file doesn't:

```
ansible@node1:~$ curl https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.


ansible@node1:~$ curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/ssl/keycloak-rootCA.pem https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master
{"realm":"master","public_key":"...","token-service":"https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect","account-service":"https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master/account","tokens-not-before":0}
```

#### JWT Token

The payload of my JWT token looks the following:

```
{
  "jti": "455feab7-5828-49f3-9243-a2ce0a1ae6f9",
  "exp": 1557246081,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1557246021,
  "iss": "https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "78f9bdc8-d1a4-43c4-ab83-f1b4645519f6",
  "typ": "ID",
  "azp": "account",
  "auth_time": 1557246020,
  "session_state": "ccafaa62-a888-43dd-9135-1c5a31766e0b",
  "acr": "1",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Testuser",
  "groups": [
    "group1",
    "k8s-admin"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "dummy-username",
  "given_name": "Firstname1",
  "family_name": "Lastname1",
  "email": "me@example.com"
}
```

When I try to login with the token of a generated service account (from kubernetes) everything works fine.

### additional Information

The environment was set up via Kubespray and the API server parameters specified in the following way:

```
kube_oidc_url: https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master
kube_oidc_client_id: account
kube_oidc_ca_file: "{{ kube_cert_dir }}/keycloak-rootCA.pem"
kube_oidc_username_claim: sub
kube_oidc_groups_claim: groups
#kube_oidc_username_prefix: "oidc:"
#kube_oidc_groups_prefix: "oidc:"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that Kubespray did not overtake my settings into the Pod spec of the api-server (/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml). When I added the parameters in the Pod spec of each api-server (I have a multi master setup), it worked as expected:

```
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master
- --oidc-client-id=account
- --oidc-username-claim=email
- '--oidc-username-prefix=oidc:'
- --oidc-groups-claim=groups
- '--oidc-groups-prefix=oidc:'
- --oidc-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/keycloak-rootCA.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case `kube_oidc_url` should be `https://192.168.178.25:8443`

Also make note of CA certificates requirement from [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/):

> A note about requirement #3 above, requiring a CA signed certificate.
>   If you deploy your own identity provider (as opposed to one of the
>   cloud providers like Google or Microsoft) you MUST have your identity
>   provider’s web server certificate signed by a certificate with the CA
>   flag set to TRUE, even if it is self signed. This is due to GoLang’s
>   TLS client implementation being very strict to the standards around
>   certificate validation. If you don’t have a CA handy, you can use this
>   script from the CoreOS team to create a simple CA and a signed
>   certificate and key pair. Or you can use this similar script that
>   generates SHA256 certs with a longer life and larger key size.

Comment: thanks for your comment Vasily Angapov. The CA file has this flag set (`X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical CA:TRUE`). Changing the `kube_oidc_url` didn't effect the result (acutually I am wondering that there is no different error, because the documentation says that a `.well-known/openid-configuration` must exist on this path (in this case `https://192.168.178.25:8443/.well-known/openid-configuration`) what isn't the case. Instead it exists for `https://192.168.178.25:8443/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration`). 
Any other ideas?